# Stop menu closing when clicked

Tags: menu-bar

Im a new OSX user, and coming from Windows if I click a menu item which has a child popout menu I expect it to open the child not close the whole menu.

<strike>This seems to be system wide</strike> **This seems to be within the main menu bar and not context menus**, is there a setting I can change to stop the click closing the menu?

Comment: What do you call a “child popout menu” exactly? If it's a submenu, clicking it should simply do nothing, not close the menu.

Comment: Steps to replicate, in `finder` click `go` then click `recent folders` and the menu disappears

Comment: Oh, interesting. Testing on 10.6: Finder and iTunes indeed present this behavior, but iCal, Mail, Safari don't…

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such setting. If it existed, it would most probably be in System Preferences > Appearance.

However, this behavior seems to depend on the application. On my 10.6 system, the Finder and iTunes indeed present it, but iCal, Mail and Safari don't.

I unfortunately have no idea as to the root cause for this difference, and which programs might behave in which way.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I will have to learn to not be so hasty with the clicking.